Como hago que un textbox se complete en formato decimal en vb.net
no se me ocurre otra forma de describir lo que quiero hacer mas que con una referencia a excel, tengo un textbox en un form que se visualiza con 2 números decimales, el problema es que no encuentro como hacer que un numero entero por ejemplo: 1 se vuelva 1.00 automáticamente luego de presionar enter o tab, en Excel las celdas se formatean fácilmente dándole una propiedad numérica, al ingresar el numero entero cambia automáticamente a decimal de acuerdo a cuantos decimales se le haya asignado a la celda o column, cual seria el equivalente a ese formateo en vb.net?

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! vb.net o c#??? igual no pusiste nada de lo que intentaste, que basicamente es en el evento que quieras, al salir del textbox hacer un format al contenido del campo... o usar un campo masked... o yo que se.. pero como no mostraste mucho, mucho no se puede ayudar...

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

y el codigo de lo que has intentdo que no funciona donde esta???

Intenta con:
    Private Sub texto_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles texto.KeyPress

    If Not [String].IsNullOrWhiteSpace(texto.Text) And e.KeyChar = Convert.ToChar(Keys.Return) Then
        texto.Text = FormatNumber(texto.Text, 2)
    End If
End Sub


Tu si que entendiste la pregunta hermano, funciono perfecto 10/10
